# Integrate a QNAP TS-128A NAS in ESXi

Tags: vmware-esxi, network-attached-storage, qnap

Hello dear community,

I would like to mount / integrate a QNAP TS-128A NAS as storage in an VMWare ESXi 6.7 via "Mount NFS data storage". I had managed this several times without any problems. This time, however, this error message appears in the ESXi:

"**The mount request was denied by the NFS server. Check whether the export exists and the client is authorized to mount**"

I went through everything. Does somebody has any idea?

kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Host access had the wrong IP (one digit was wrong).